# Method for decomposing time-intervals of univariate Time-Series

Tags: time-series, stationarity, decomposition

I am no expert in time-series analysis but trying to get a more of a grasp of it.

So, during a Light/Dark transition test the activity of animals is tracked. During the light-phase, usually low to no activity while during dark-phases a high activity can be observed. While this is the natural activity, we also research deviations and different behavior patterns. So in the first case, the result is a non-stationary time series which of course depends on the external variable of whether its light or dark. A visualization of the "natural" behavior is as followed (heavily idealized):

[image: ![Outcome of a Light/Dark transition test. After the light is turned off (black lines) a rapid increase can be observed which is constant until the light is turned on again (orange lines)]

The problem is, that the obtained time series have large amounts of time points. So I would like to decompose the univariate time series into sub-time series, whereas every sub-time series should be one of the four phases (in the specific example presented) that can be observed:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Now the most simple solution (at least in my opinion) would be to apply linear regression and define a threshold for the correlation coefficient which determines when a new phase would start.

Now, the implementation for the specific pattern presented is not exactly what I am asking for. As there are more, different patterns in the dataset a specific solution for the presented pattern would not seal the deal. I would like to ask the community whether they know of examples where people tried this: to apply an algorithm that identifies characteristic phases of a time series and decomposes it into them.

I would be very glad for pointers toward great literature, tutorials, or something else.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you know vs. what you need. Do you know if the phases are regular in time or not? If so, do you know what the interval is, or do you need to fit this? Do you know the values/shapes you'd expect given that you're in a particular phase?